# How to get unique value in multidimensional 3D array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How I can get uniques values from a **multidimensional array**?

```php
$arr = array(
    array(
        array("avg"),
        array("responsecnt"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete"),
    ),
    array(
        array("avg","responsecnt"),
        array("responsecnt"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete"),
    ),
    array(
        array("avg","abc"),
        array("responsecnt","xyz"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete", "yes"),
    ),
    array(
        array("avg"),
        array("responsecnt"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete"),
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
//find unique value
```

I need some way to find unique values in the array above. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: And please... format that code.

Comment: yes i have tired entire the day.Still trying for some solution.

Comment: @Manoranjan you have to approve a pending edit.

Comment: @Manoranjan Show us your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script and I think you will see how to do what you want done.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        array("avg"),
        array("responsecnt"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete")
    ),
    array(
        array("avg","responsecnt"),
        array("responsecnt"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete")
    ),
    array(
        array("avg","abc"),
        array("responsecnt","xyz"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete", "yes"),
    ),
    array(
        array("avg"),
        array("responsecnt"),
        "other" => array ("surveycomplete"),
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($arr[$i]);$j++){
        for($k=0;$k<sizeof($arr[$i][$j]);$k++){
            echo $arr[$i][$j][$k]."<br>";
        }
    }
    for($l=0;$l<sizeof($arr[$i]["other"]);$l++)
    {echo $arr[$i]["other"][$l]."<br>";}
}
```

Comment: sorry i  need  unique values in the array above. if it present it first one not should be come in next successive array. Unique Array element.